# Permutation and Combinations in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I will like to find the most optimized way of doing search on Pandas DataFrame

For example

I will like to search for value

```
aaa = 9 in the dataframe df
```

### df

```
  index Column  value
   1     aaa      1
   2     aaa      3
   3     aaa      5
   4     aaa     -3 
   5     aaa      3
   6     aaa      0
```

It should result in the following

```
Answer: Combinations of Index locations (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,6),(1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,3,5), (1,3,5,6)
```

as they all sum upto **9**

I am avoiding to run permutation loop for n^n times for all combinations.
Any short cuts will be highly appreciated

Comment: Potentially useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to find indices where the corresponding column is equal to `aaa` AND the sum of values is 9?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the brute-force method using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). You can optimize by using a generator and stop summing when values exceed a total of 9.

```
from itertools import combinations

d = df.set_index('index')['value'].to_dict()

n = len(d)
res = [i for j in range(n) for i in combinations(d, j) if sum(map(d.get, i)) == 9]

print(res)

[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted jpp's answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame([['aaa', 1],['aaa',3], ['aaa',5], ['aaa',-3], ['aaa', 3], ['aaa',0]], columns=['A', 'B'],index=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
res = [i for j in range(1,df.index.size+1) for i in itertools.combinations(df.index,j) if df.loc[i, 'B'].sum() == 9]
print res
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```